# Javascript/jQuery change word color by specific some text contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question with jQuery Css.

I would like to change color of my text by specific word contains using jQuery.

I have example like this:

```
<div class="me">I'm Groot</div>
```

1. I'm <-- will be always black color
2. Groot <-- will be always green color and Groot sometimes can be change with another word.

How can I do that with jQuery or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all occurrences of your specific text snippets with custom styled html elements:

```js
const yourName = "Groot";

const element = document.querySelector(".me");
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML
    .replace("I'm", `<span class="black-class">I'm</span>`)
    .replace(yourName, `<span class="green-class">${yourName}</span>`);
```

Alternatively you can also make everything green except the `I'm` like this:

```css
.me {
  color: green;
}
```

```js
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML
    .replace("I'm", `<span class="black-class">I'm</span>`);
```

This way not only `Groot` is colored green but everything inside of the `div`. That way your JavaScript doesn't need to know the name.

Comment: Hi, as I explained above, Groot can be another name.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave I put the name into a variable, is that how you need it?

Comment: Yeah. So whatever on const yourName, it will change the color to be green right? I will try it

Comment: Long code doesn't necessarily mean it's the correct solution btw, Yeah it solves it but at what cost, take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Just group them like so
:

```
<div class="me">I'm <span id="changer">Groot</span></div>
```

Then for CSS, style it like so:

```
#changer {
    color: green;
}
```

Then to change with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Changed";
```

Which of course you can add a setTimeout to change continuously

---

Edit:
No problem, since the only part changing is "Groot" part,
So:

```
var changing = "Groot";
$('.me').text(`I'm <span id="changer">${changing}</span>`);
// then from here the value of the $('#changer') can be accessed and changed
$('#changer').text('Not Groot');
```

Comment: Hi, how about if .me value get from string? Example, $(‘.me’).text(textFromString)